# Get XML attribute Values by its Descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML in this Format and I want to get List of Line `ID` and its `Name`

```
<ArrayOfLines xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <LineStatus ID="0" StatusDetails="">
        <BranchDisruptions />
        <Line ID="1" Name="Line1" />
        <Status ID="GS" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Good Service" IsActive="true">
            <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line" />
        </Status>
    </LineStatus>
    <LineStatus ID="1" StatusDetails="">
        <BranchDisruptions />
        <Line ID="2" Name="Line2" />
        <Status ID="GS" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Good Service" IsActive="true">
            <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line" />
        </Status>
    </LineStatus>
</ArrayOfLines>
```

and This is the code I have written:

```
String xmlFilePath = @"C:/myXML.xml";
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
var query = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("LineStatus") select c;
```

but it is not returning me any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an [xml namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to specify it with element names:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var query = from c in xmlFile.Descendants(ns + "LineStatus") select c;
```

Comment: Thanks, How Will I get these values now <Line ID="1" Name="Line1" />
I did.
 foreach (XElement element in query)
            {
                      foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
}, but stuck here

Comment: @user3745020 you don't need `foreach`, you can do it through Anonymous Types. Refer my answer below.

Comment: Strange. The code in this answer should return nothing, unless the XML namespace declared as default namespace instead of prefixed namespace (prefixed namespace only applies if the element use corresponding prefix : `<xsi:LineStatus>`)

Comment: @har, thats because it is not xml namespace it is xmlns:xsi mentioned here

Comment: @user3745020 `xmlns:xsi` is an [XML namespace declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#ns-decl) (or see: [Wikipedia : XML Namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace), particularly *Namespace declaration* section)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my idea but you have to create list "namesList" and "idList" before. Try this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("your xml file");
foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("line"))
{
    idList.Add(elem.Attribute("ID").Value);
    namesList.Add(elem.Attribute("Name").Value);
}
```

And you have full controll by index of each list to this data. After that you can also create object of these 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
String xmlFilePath = @"C:/myXML.xml";
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
var query = (from c in xmlFile.Descendants("Line") 
             select new { 
                          ID=c.Attribute("ID").Value,
                          Name=c.Attribute("Name").Value
                        }).ToList();;
```